# adding a suffix in a for loop in bash

Tags: bash

This is the /tmp/foo file

```
cat /tmp/foo ---->   monohajo,wuem,taraziem,mullanke,fernanja

$ for i in $(cat /tmp/foo | awk -F':' '{print $NF}');
do
echo "update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = '"$i{xx}"' where user_name = '"$i"' ";
done | tr -d "{}"

update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'monohajoxx' where user_name = 'monohajo'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'wuemxx' where user_name = 'wuem'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'taraziemxx' where user_name = 'taraziem'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'mullankexx' where user_name = 'mullanke'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'fernanjaxx' where user_name = 'fernanja'
```

The $i{xx} is troublesome because I am not deleting the names from the database, I am just adding a xx (changing them)
I cheap hacked it with the tr where i take out the {} at the end.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: A good way would be to show actual data.  If the file is comma separated, why are you passing `-F':'` to awk?  Where does the `---->` come from?  Is the input file one line of comma separated words as shown, or is it 5 lines?

Comment: But I think all you need to do is `... set user_name = '"${i}xx"'` to separate the `xx` from the name of the variable.

Comment: Oh you are right - I got the names from a colon delimited file - hence the awk -F ": : "

Comment: thank you  - I was close with the I{xx}

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access a variable in a string that is immediately followed by other characters, you can separate the variable name from the rest by using curly braces:

```
for i in mono hajo tara;
do
    echo "change $i into ${i}xx"
done
```

Returns:

```
change mono into monoxx
change hajo into hajoxx
change tara into taraxx
```

However, the first part of your script confuses me. `foo` seems to constist of a comma separated list of names. `awk -F':' '{print $NF}'` will print out the last field of this, assuming that the fields are colon-separated.

Which they are not. So the 'last' field is also the first (and only) field, meaning that the full line is output (including commas).

But then the output that you show is not consistent. It would be more like a single line:

```
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'monohajo,wuem,taraziem,mullanke,fernanjaxx' where user_name = 'monohajo,wuem,taraziem,mullanke,fernanja'
```

Comment: thank you - I got the names from a colon delimited list - hence the awk -F ' : '